# Dynamically create h1 tags using swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, swiftsoup

My question is how can I dynamically create h1 tags using Swift and add it to the front of the HTML file.

This is what I have and it is not working.

```
extension WKWebView {

func loadHTML(html: String) {
    let htmlString = """
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <h1> + String(htmlEncodedString:post.title) + </h1>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
    <span>\(html)</span>
    """
    self.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
} }
```

and this is the output 
" + String(htmlEncodedString:post.title) + "

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: the desired output is the value of post.title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use interpolation:

```
let htmlString = """
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<h1> + \(String(htmlEncodedString:post.title)) + </h1>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
<span>\(html)</span>
"""
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much I appreciate your help